# Extracting number of likes on Instagram post

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I am very new to coding, and I am trying to write a code in PyCharm that compares my followers to the people that liked and commented on my posts. The end goal is to get a list of the followers that have not interacted with a single post.

I am getting stuck at the part where I have to extract the number of likes on a post. I've tried multiple things, but the only way I've gotten the code to work so far is by putting the number of likes in manually:

```
#extract likers & commenters
time.sleep(1)
extractlikers = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href*='liked']"))).click()

time.sleep(1.5)
likedbywindow = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style*='hidden auto']")))

while True:
    driver.execute_script(
        'arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;',
        likedbywindow)

    listoflikers = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='_7UhW9   xLCgt        qyrsm KV-D4           se6yk       T0kll ']")
    numberoflikers = len(listoflikers)
    if (numberoflikers == 23):
        break
```

How can I replace the '23' so that I don't have to adjust the number manually for every post?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Here's the URL of the post:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CaFzLHuMhW6/

HTML from element:

```
<div class="_7UhW9   xLCgt        qyrsm KV-D4              fDxYl    T0kll "><span>22</span> others</div>
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant url ot text based HTML of the element.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect. But maybe you should check position after scrolling - and if it doesn't change position then you have end of page. Eventually you should compare `numberoflikers` with value from previous loop `numberoflikers == previous_numberoflikers` to see if there are new likers.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I have added the URL of the specific post. Hope that helps!

Comment: @furas That actually sounds like it makes more sense than my idea. I will try that tonight and see if I can get the code to work. I'll update you!